# add watermark to video and image with input and output array bytes

Tags: arrays, go, ffmpeg, byte, watermark

I'm trying to add watermark to images and videos using [ffmpeg](https://github.com/u2takey/ffmpeg-go). My files are stored on `AWS S3`, so they are byte arrays (`[]byte`).

I need my input and output to be in a byte array and not saved to disk.

I tried something like the code and it didn't work:

```
    buffFile := bytes.NewBuffer(file)
    out := &bytes.Buffer{}
    overlay := ffmpeg.Input("pipe:", ffmpeg.KwArgs{}).Filter("scale", ffmpeg.Args{"64:-1"}).WithInput(buffWatermark)
    err = ffmpeg.Filter(
        []*ffmpeg.Stream{
            ffmpeg.Input("pipe:", ffmpeg.KwArgs{}).WithInput(buffFile),
            overlay,
        }, "overlay", ffmpeg.Args{"10:10"}, ffmpeg.KwArgs{"enable": "gte(t,1)"}).
        Output("pipe:", ffmpeg.KwArgs{}).WithOutput(out).OverWriteOutput().ErrorToStdOut().Run()
```

Comment: Create a command using the `exec` package. Set its stdin to your byte buffer containing the video. Set its stdout to another buffer where you'll capture the output.